# Starting universal windows apps (UWA) from powershell in windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm creating a script that is launching an app from Windows 10 powershell.

Is there a way to start installed (*.appx) application from powershell? The app is launching fine from home menu.

I've tried to google around, but haven't found any answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the app registers a protocol activation URI, you can use

```
Start-Process uri
```

to activate it. For example:

```
Start-Process xbox://
```

launches the xbox UWP app. The trick is finding out what the protocol activation URIs. You can see a list of the currently installed ones if you open the classic control panel and go to

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations

and scroll all the way to the bottom under (Protocols). Not all of those are UWP apps, however, and i don't know a programmatic way to enumerate them that I can find with a quick search.

Obviously, if this is for your own app, you can just register a unique protocol activation URI yourself (and even make it do fancy things depending on the parameters for customization)

Comment: thanks a lot Andrew, I'll test this approach. It just might be too hard to find uri automatically with script from powershell.